Must all correlation functions come from a measure?
In the Wightman setting a quantum field is defined as an operator valued distribution satisfying the Wightman axioms. Using the vacuum state of this theory we can define correlation/Wightman functions that are known to satisfy certain properties.
We can also work in the opposite direction. Given a set of scalar-valued distributions $\{W_n\}$ obeying certain properties there is an associated unique quantum field theory (in other words, a unique set of operator-valued distributions obeying the Wightman axioms for which the $W_n$ are its correlation functions) thanks to the Wightman reconstruction theorem.
If we are given a measure $\mu$ then we can of course define correlation functions by taking moments of $\mu$ and check if these moments satisfy the conditions needed to invoke the Wightman reconstruction theorem. However the reconstruction theorem itself makes no mention of a measure $\mu$, so $\{W_n\}$ doesn't necessarily have to be moments of some measure.
At what point does the measure $\mu$ enter? Do we always consider a measure because of motivation from physics and the path integral? That is, when rigorously constructing quantum field theories do we always study correlation functions arising from a measure because these are the only theories that are physically relevant? I am trying to distinguish the physics and the mathematics behind these constructions.

Just to clarify formalism, a correlation functions of a Wightman field theory cannot arise from a measure. Measures describe classical probability theories, whereas a Wightman field is noncommutative. What is true is that for a bosonic Wightman field, one can use the Bargmann-Hall-Wightman theorem in order to analytically continue the Wightman functions into the non-coincident Euclidean points. One obtains analytic functions $S(x_1,\dots, x_n)$ (at non-coincident points). These are known as Schwinger functions, and they are symmetric under permutations of the coordinates. Because of this symmetry, one can hope that they truly arise as moments of a probability measure $\mu$.
However, this is actually FALSE in general. A necessary condition for Schwinger functions to arise from a probability measure is what is known as Nelson-Symanzik positivity. The condition is not too surprising: If $\mu$ is a probability measure, then we should expect that for any sequence of test functions $f_0, \dots, f_n$ where $f_i \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^{di})$, we have
$$\sum_{n,m} S_{n+m}(x_1,\dots, x_n, y_1, \dots, y_m)f^\ast_n(x_1,\dots, x_n)f_m(y_1, \dots, y_m)\geq 0$$
This is the obvious consequence of the claim that $\mu$ is a measure. All this comes from is the fact that the above expression is equal to
$$\int \bigg|\sum_{n} \int f_n(x_1,\dots, x_n)\phi(x_1)\dots\phi(x_n)dx_1\dots dx_n\bigg|^2d\mu(\phi)\geq 0$$
Finally, it is not expected that every physical quantum field theory arises from a measure. For example, in gauge theories with fermions, one finds the relation for the axial current  $\partial_\mu j^\mu = \frac{ie}{\pi}F$. The occurrence of these complex numbers immediately kills your chances for finding a probability measure generating the Schwinger functions for the observable fields $(j^\mu, F_{\mu\nu})$. (See Gauge Theories as a Problem of Constructive Quantum Field Theory and Statistical Mechanics for details)
However for less complicated models, such as purely bosonic field theories with polynomial interactions, one can typically always expect a measure theoretic/probabilistic representation of the model.

Thank you! This is interesting as I had always thought that reflection positivity is motived by wanting the norm of the constructed Hilbert space to be positive definite. However, your answer suggests that there is something deeper going on here and reflection positivity says the Schwinger functions arise from a measure. Are the these two points somehow saying the same thing?

I am not familiar with the axial current example you gave, but I have not yet encountered a QFT that cannot be written as a path integral. If every physical quantum field theory doesn't arise from a measure what does that mean for the theory? I would guess it means that there is an issue with writing down a Lagrangian for it? How much of this goes through for fermionic theories?

Also, why would we expect your first expression to be non-negative if $\mu$ is a measure? And how is it equal to the expression below it?

Reflection positivity is not the same as Nelson-Symanzik positivity. Nelson-Symanzik positivity is a necessary condition for the Schwinger functions to be moments of a measure. Reflection positivity is a necessary condition for the Schwinger functions to analytically continue to a set of WIghtman functions.

The notion of 'path integral' used by physicists is a bit broad. For example fermionic path integrals are not integrals against measures. So the issue is much more down to earth than the existence or lack thereof of a lagrangian. After all, the gauge theories with fermions that I mentioned certainly have corresponding Lagrangians.

As for your last question, it's nonnegative because a probability measure is nonnegative. The two expressions can be seen to be the same by simply expanding the square.

Nelson-Symanzik positivity seems to be a very important property, yet it is often omitted from most presentations of the OS axioms. Is there any reason why this is? Most textbooks make no mention of it yet everything is written with the implication that the Schwinger functions arise as moments of some measure.

Because it is not required for the OS axioms. The OS axioms are essentially the bare minimum you need to get a quantum field theory. Nelson-Symanzik positivity is an additional property that may or may not hold for some quantum field theories. It's useful when it's there, but it is not physically necessary. Also I am not sure what books you have in mind, but introductory material will tend to focus on simple $P(\phi)$ models where these subtleties do not arise.

Yes you are right, most of the books I am referring to only focus on $P(\phi)$ models such as the books by Glimm & Jaffe or by Simon. Are there any other books you can suggest that discuss these subtleties?

Simon's book actually has a very good discussion of these exact subtleties.

I'll take another look at it, thanks for all your help!
